# Event to listen Auto fill in Starling AS 3

Tags: starling-framework

I am using text input in starling and running it on Android devices.When user filling it using keyboard,suggestions come on top of keyboard to auto fill.How can I know that user auto fill the text input by clicking directly on any suggestions.Is there any event to listen it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your description correctly it sounds like your app using the native text field. In this case you don't have control over it. It's pure implementation of the android keyboard application and those are not telling you what the user is doing. It may create some security problems, for example when you are typing password or some like that, it may be catched by other applications as well. So you only getting events from the textComponent it self after the editing is complete.